# Bash script: Using "script" command from a bash script for logging a session

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use `script` command for logging a bash session.

The `script` command is executed from withing a bash script but as soon as it is executed, the bash script terminates.

I have tried to invoke the command using various combination always with the same result (termination of the bash script as soon as the command is called). The output that I get is the following:

```
Script started, file is typescript
root@ubuntu: ...
```

I have also tried to invoke the command with an `&` in the end but again with no luck.

Can anyone tell me how should I invoke the command from a bash script?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your bash script, or at least the `script` line.

Comment: From the script prompt do a ps (no parameters), that should show what is happening.  Why do you think it is not working?  If it is because typescript is "empty", then you are suffering from buffering.

Comment: @Robin Green: You can find my script here: [link](http://pastebin.com/CuAyPfhM)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your shell script did not terminate. It is still running. You are getting a prompt because `script` is spawning a new shell. the prompt you see is the prompt from the spawned shell.

The normal use case for `script` is something like this:

1. start `script`. this spawns a new shell.
2. do commands in the new shell.
3. exit the shell and drop to previous shell
4. examine the logfile created by `script`

So basically `script` is working as expected. You will have to find another way to achieve what you want.

You can log the execution of your script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec > logfile 2>&1
set -x
FOO=BAR
echo $FOO
```

Explanation:

- `exec > logfile 2>&1` redirects stdout and stderr to logfile
- `set -x` makes bash print every command before executing it

Example:

```
$ ./foo.sh
  # (no output here because everything goes to logfile)
$ cat logfile 
+ FOO=BAR
+ echo BAR
BAR
```

Disadvantage of this method is that the script prints no output for humans to see. Everything goes to the logfile.

Alternatively you can do it like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
# nothing special here
FOO=BAR
echo $FOO
```

Then execute like this:

```
$ script -c "bash -x foo.sh"
Script started, file is typescript
+ FOO=BAR
+ echo BAR
BAR
Script done, file is typescript
```

now output is directly visible and also saved to logfile (default name of logfile is `typescript`)

```
$ cat typescript 
Script started on Mi 18 Mai 2011 01:05:29 CEST
+ FOO=BAR
+ echo BAR
BAR

Script done on Mi 18 Mai 2011 01:05:29 CEST
```

Comment: With the BSD script command (MacOS X) you don't use the `-c` argument or quotes around the command. It will be `script bash -x foo.sh`

Comment: to append log file use ```cmd2 >> logfile.log```

Answer (score 6):

Your bash script is still running, but it has spawned a new interactive shell. The bash script is waiting for `script` to complete, which will only happen when the interactive shell is terminated (either by being killed, or by the user typing `exit`).

To make the command after `script` be logged by `script`, do it like this:

```
script build_log -c 'echo -e "* This line should appear inside the /"build_log/" log file..."'
```

However, `script` will stop running after running that command.

To run multiple commands inside `script`, put those commands inside another bash script and specify that bash script as the command to run to the `-c` option.

Comment: Thank you! this was EXACTLY what I was looking for. I doing a lot of make x, make y, etc and scripting them individually at the command line. I ended up using one .sh file and called `script results1.txt -c "make x"` for each of my make commands. VERY USEFUL!

Comment: With the BSD script command (MacOS X) you don't need the `-c` argument or quotes around the command. It will be `script build_log echo '* This line should appear inside the "build_log" log file...'`

Answer (score 3):

Following execve's idea, you can also use an environment variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$TYPESCRIPT" ] && TYPESCRIPT=1 exec /usr/bin/script -c "TYPESCRIPT=1 $0 $@"
# your script here...
```

Answer (score 3):

juj's answer is great but fails to pass on arguments correctly. The basic problem is the use of `$@` inside a double-quoted string. `$*` should be used instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$TYPESCRIPT" ] && TYPESCRIPT=1 exec /usr/bin/script -c "TYPESCRIPT=1  $0 $*"
# your script here...
```

Here's what happens with `$@`:

`foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z $FOO ]
then
    FOO=1 exec $0 $@
else
    ./echo_args.sh "$0 $@"
fi
```

`bar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 0 $0
echo 1 $1
echo 2 $2
echo 3 $3
```

Now `./foo.sh with some arguments` outputs

```
0 ./bar.sh
1 /path/to/foo.sh with
2 some
3 arguments
```

This would cause some of the arguments to be passed to `script` instead of to the second execution of `foo.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trick within your shell script to start script or not start it. Based on a special argument, it can choose to execute  itself with a special argument so that script is not started again.

This should most likely explain what I mean:

```
if [ "$1" != "noscript" ] ; then
        # execute self with the noscript special arg so that the second execution DOES NOT start script again.
        exec script -q -c "$0 noscript $1 $2 $3" /build/buildlog_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`.log
        echo Problem in $0, please check.
        exit 1;
fi 
...Rest of the script should follow here.
```

I have tried this, and it works well. Unless you are particular about the kind of arguments that need to be passed as well as the script is planned to be used by hostile users, this should suffice :).