# "script command" and logging in python

Tags: python, linux, command

I have a python app that has lots of outputs on the screen which can be used for debugging. out of all the logging techniques, "script" command works well for me because I can see the output on the screen as well as logging it. I want to include that at the beginning of my python app to run automatically and log everything, when I do, however, the python program doesn't run. as soon as I type exit at the terminal (which stops script logging) the app starts working. The command I'm using is:

```
command="script /tmp/appdebug/debug.txt"
os.system(command)
```

I have also tried script -q but the same issue is there. Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did find the answer for anyone who is interested:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507602/logging-all-bash-in-and-out-with-script-command

and

[Bash script: Using "script" command from a bash script for logging a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session)

I will keep this question as others might have the same issue and finding those answers wasn't exactly easy :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `subprocess`, like so:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['script', '/tmp/appdebug/debug.txt'], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`script` is a *wrapper* for a session of interactions.  Even if it appears to terminate quickly after being started in a shell, this is not so; instead it starts a new shell *in which* you can interact so that everything is logged to a file.

What does this mean for you?

Your approach of using `script` cannot work.  You start `script` using `os.system` which will wait for `script` to terminate before the next Python statement is executed.  `script`'s work will only happen before it terminates (i. e. during the uninteresting waiting period of your Python program).

I propose to use `script -c yourprog.py yourprog.log` instead.  This will execute and wrap the `yourprog.py` and the session will be stored in `yourprog.log`.