# script command - bash linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I am running the cmd

```
script install-log.txt
```

the terminal successfully returns

```
Script started, file is install-log.txt
```

If I begin typing commands and receiving output to the screen

```
lsblk
fdisk -l
ls
echo ok
```

when I check the install-log.txt

```
nano install-log.txt
```

it is empty.

I thought all cmd was supposed to be saved there until the session is finished?

I am using Arch-Linux installation CD, and wanted to save this log to record my installation setup cmds.

Comment: You have to close your console (end your script session) or reach 1 block (512bytes, 2048bytes or something depending on your fs or even more depending on your cache config) before you may see something in output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to terminate script operation by running 'exit' command. That wont exit your terminal as such. Then you can view your log file.

Here is the duplicate with more detailed info -> [Bash script: Using "script" command from a bash script for logging a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session)

Comment: exit seemed to work, however examining the contents of the file for even 1 command logged shows alot of verbiage, such as **^[[1m^[[7m#^[[27m^[[1m^[[0m** Do you know why this is present, is there a viewer which ignore this?

Comment: Certain interactive commands, such as vi, create garbage in the typescript file. Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal. If you run "cat install-log.txt" then you don't see those garbage printed.

Comment: cat install-log.txt displays only the first line of text in the log file, **Script done on Sat 13 Sep 2014...**

Comment: No, it will display everything, the output may be confusing because it looks same as the commands that you have run. After exiting from script, do this -> run "date", then cat install-log.txt and then you will see the o/p that is printed after the date

Comment: It still displays only 1 line from the log file, running nano log will return the whole log, but with the verbiage.

Running head logfile provides a clean viewable logfile, however specifying the lines required is annoying