# How to run "script -a xxx.txt" properly in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script and I want the session text to be saved automatically every time the script runs, so I included the command "script -a output.txt" at the beginning of my script. However, the script stops running after this line of code, which only displays a "bash-3.2$" on the screen and won't go on. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `script` starts an interactive subshell, that's why the script blocks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session)

Comment: @dramzy: Exactly! failed to look it up earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: Using "script" command from a bash script for logging a session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is script starts a separate *sub-shell* than the one that is running the actual script, to club them together. Use the `-c` flag in `script`

```
-c, --command command
       Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes
       it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that
       behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.
```

Just do,

```
script -c 'bash yourScript.sh' -a output.txt
```

Comment: Hi Inian! Thanks for your prompt reply! Thus would the output still be appended? Or should I use script -ca 'bash script.sh'? Thanks! I will try later

Comment: @Hang: You need to specify the `-a` option too!

Comment: Hi sorry Inian just got a chance to test the command. After I added this to my script when executing it, it said "script: illegal option -- c
usage: script [-adkpqr] [-t time] [file [command ...]]". I've googled around and didn't find anything specific to "script -c"(to my shock! Most are for stat or date or sth). By the way I'm using zsh, tried to change back to bash by "exec bash" with no luck. Any ideas? :D

Comment: @Hang: You don't have to add this in a script, run `script -c 'bash yourScript.sh' -a output.txt` this on the command line, it will run the script internally and log in `output.txt`

Comment: Thanks wow you're right here when I commend it! :D But ideally I want this to be executed automatically when I run the script. So if that's possible? I actually will schedule this script to run automatically in a daily basis

Comment: @Hang: Run the command you used in a different script say, e.g. `anotherScript.sh` which has the line `script -c 'bash yourScript.sh' -a output.txt`

Comment: Gotcha! Let me try. Thanks for your continuous help! ;D

Comment: Thanks Inian! Definitely! Well I just tried putting these simple two lines in a textEdit and chmod 700 it: cd ~/Documents
script -c 'bash ScriptTest' -a testOutput.txt
Then execute it with the output: Last login: Mon Jan 23 02:39:30 on ttys001
macos-10:~ chenhang$ /Users/chenhang/Documents/anotherShell ; exit;
script: illegal option -- c
usage: script [-adkpqr] [-t time] [file [command ...]]
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Is there anything I did wrong? :(

Comment: @Hang: Can you run it under `bash` with a proper she-bang(`#!/bin/bash`) at the top of the script? and did you set execute permissions to `chmod +x <script>`

Comment: Yea my bad I've added #!/bin/bash to the first line. About "chmod +x <script>" could you explain more what command should I type in Terminal? Thanks!

Comment: @Hang: Were you able to run the script now?