# "script" command exits bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

im trying to write a script that should also output a log file of everything that happens.
the command i found to do that is "script" but my "myscript.sh" exits after running "script" is there any way to prevent my shell script to exit?

"myscript.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh

timeStamp="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T)"
script script-install-edx-${timeStamp}.log

printf "question"

        read answer
        case $answer in
                    y|Y )   echo Yes
                            runAll=false
                    ;;
                    n|N )   echo no
                            runAll=true
                    ;;
                    * )     echo else;;
        esac
```

Comment: `script` spawns a new shell, and it is in that shell where the commands that are typed are logged to the file specified by the command that launched script. You can use the script `-c` flag to specify the commands that you wish to run inside that shell. You may be able to stick the rest of your bash script in a heredoc as the parameter for the `-c` flag too. Not sure on that option though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hit on google...

[Bash script: Using "script" command from a bash script for logging a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session)

Script command opens a new shell, your script is still running in the background

Comment: This is a stackoverflow link. Please use the "Close" button on the question and mark it as a duplicate using this link as the link instead of posting it as it's separate answer.

Comment: thanks!
i googled but i havent found that, i guess i have used the "wrong" search terms