# Is there a way to audit the SPARK shell commands so as to log and secure the spark data privacy access

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to audit the SPARK shell commands. Like there is way in MapR for auditing the maprcli commands, auditing the MaprFS etc.
Similarly is there is a way to Audit Spark Shell, Spark Sql, Spark Data access - and audit the info like who, when & what performed etc.

Comment: Probably you could use something like `script` command and then audit the output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session

Comment: Custom functions that println the commands to console/logs. Lets say you have a function called inputTable(numberRecords : Long, sourceHiveTable : String, userName : String, timeStamp: Timestamp); you could have println(sourceHiveTable + " was processed by " + userName + "; during the interaction they pulled " + numberRecords.toString + " number of records, at this time " + timeStamp.toString)